# TypeScript display alert message

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, typescript

Within the controller I have add function that will return a message that the agent name is already in used. I dont understand how to used the typescript callback to display the error message to the user.

> Do I need to change how typescript is processing the response?
>
> "{"Message":"An error has
>   occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"\r\n\r\nMapping
>   types:\r\nAgentInformationModel

TypeScript

```
    saveAgentWithAgentInformation(agent: AgentModel, callback: Function) {
            var promise = (typeof agent.Id === "undefined" || agent.Id === null || agent.Id === 0) ?
                this.agentsService.createAgent(agent) :
                this.agentsService.updateAgentWithAgentInformation(agent);

            this.viewManager.busyIndicator.show();
            promise.then((response) => {
                callback(response);
            })
                .fail((response) => {
                    console.log(response);
                    this.notificationManager.error(response.responseJSON.Message);
                })
                .always(() => {
                    this.viewManager.busyIndicator.hide();
                });
        }
```

Controller

```
    public IHttpActionResult CreateAgent([FromBody]AgentModel agentModel)
        {
            LogHelper.Info($"Creating agent {agentModel.Name}");

            //Search if Agent name is in the system
            bool flgAgent = AgentsDataService.AgentExists(agentModel.Name);

            if (flgAgent == false)
            {
                var agentEntity = new Agent();
                Mapper.DynamicMap(agentModel, agentEntity);

                var agentInformationEntities = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<AgentInformation>>(agentModel.AgentInformations);
                agentEntity.AgentInformations = new EntitySet<AgentInformation>();
                agentEntity.AgentInformations.AddRange(agentInformationEntities);

                var operationResult = AgentsDataService.InsertAgent(agentEntity);                        

                var result = Ok(new
                {
                    Value = Mapper.Map<AgentModel>(operationResult)
                });
                return result;
            }else
            {
                string resultWarning = $"Agent Name '{agentModel.Name}' is already used";
                return Json(new
                {
                    result = false,
                    error = resultWarning
                });

                //return BadRequest(resultWarning);
            }
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it to go in the .fail section, you'll need to send a proper error message.

```
return new HttpStatusCodeResult(400, "Custom Error Message");
```

If not, then the success status will have to be part of both your success and fail return value. Then the javascript would look if .success is true or false.

Comment: Do I need to change the IHttpActionResult